# Facebook automatically delete post

Tags: facebook

On my website, people can share pages on facebook.

Also, users have the availability to allow my facebook app to post on the user page. To post on the user page, my app use a user access_token.

However, these shared pages are likely to disappear automatically within 2 weeks.

Then I was wondering if you know if facebook automatically delete a post (on a user page) if it cannot scrap the url anymore ?
I cannot find any informations regarding this ...
If the post is not deleted, is the image displayed by facebook kept somewhere ? I'd like to avoid to have horrible post related to my app on facebook ...

Comment: No, Facebook will not automatically delete anything. The data displayed in a post that shared the URL does not get automatically updated either, only if the user specifically requests it (context menu option, “refresh share attachment”)

Comment: Ok great. Do you have a reference by chance ? So if the referenced page is deleted, facebook will keep the post as originally posted (with originally scrapped image and so) ?

Comment: No, no reference. I just know that Facebook does not automatically update posts, when the OG meta data of the shared URL has changed – to prevent that I get users to share a “Look at these cute kittenz!!1” link now, and then in two weeks time change the title/description to “buy cheap v1agr4 here!” and have that show up on all their timelines …